# Can I add a light switch that overrides a set of existing switches?

Tags: electrical

I have three rows of lights. Each row has its own single pole preset dimmer switch. I want to keep them on a separate switch like that plus adding the fourth  switch to shut of all the lights with that fourth switch.

Any help please. 
Thanks

Comment: Are all the dimmers in the same box?  Have you looked at the wiring in that box?  Is there anything else in the box? Are you comfortable removing that box and adding a bigger one?

Comment: From a user experience standpoint, I predict frustration. The scenario is that you go to switch on one of the original switches and nothing happens. Maybe what you're looking for is a more advanced controller scenario, where toggling the new switch turns off all lights but doesn't disable the other switches.

Comment: I foresee a problem with dimmers losing state.  Most do not give any consideration to having power severed to them, they don't have NVRAM to remember the dimmer setting you had them at, or whether they were last on or off.  Expect to have to turn the main switch on, then turn on and set each dimmer every time.  Or... use clunky old mechanical dimmers, which *tend* not to play well with LED.

Comment: Yes that is what I am looking for .

Comment: Yes the switches are all in one box. And I don't have any problem removing the old and putting a bigger box

Comment: Nothing else is in that box

Comment: Do you want the new switch to simply be able to force the existing switches off, or to need to be turned on when you come back to the room before you can use the dimmers again?

Comment: Ok great I got it all done .

Comment: It worked perfectly.  Thanks you so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your best case scenario is that you have one hot wire that comes into your switch box and is chained to one screw of all three dimmers.  Maybe the wire comes in and is spliced into three wires that each go to a switch, or a clever person has just stripped insulation from the middle of the wire and chained it from switch to switch.  The other wire going to each dimmer would then go out to each row of lights.

[image]

*image from [https://www.do-it-yourself-help.com/wiring-two-outlets-one-box.html](https://www.do-it-yourself-help.com/wiring-two-outlets-one-box.html_)*

In this picture, the source coming in from the bottom is what I'm referring to. You would have three switches and lights, but the diagram only shows two. If you put a new switch on the incoming hot wire *before* it goes to the other dimmers (before the black wire nut in the bottom left), you will be able to cut power to everything with that one switch.

Of course that is just one way to wire the lights.  You could also have a switch loop that comes from each row, or a combination of switch loops which would make this a more complicated endeavor.